# Border css on mobile website

Tags: css, mobile, border

I have a border on the following website http://geertsprengers.be/ under the logo's of the nav.

Now the problem is that when I'm on the mobile website and there are 2 lines of logo's, the border should change the same as the arrow, below the clicked logo.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide some more information on what exactly you want to happen?

From what I could gather you want the border that is below the logos in your nav, to stay below the logos when the browser is brought down to a mobile size (when your logos go onto two rows)?

If this is the case you will simply need to do two things:

1. Change the `float: left` you have on the logos (li tags) to `display: inline-block`.
2. Change `height: 54px` you currently have on the nav to `height: auto`.

The problem is the you were trying to keep floated elements contained inside an element with a fixed height, which won't work in your case here. Instead you need to remove the fixed height, which will allow the nav to expand to fit the floated elements when they break up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, simple mistake to make.

Comment: Also, may I recommend that next time you have an issue that you add a code snippet of what you are using so people can debug your code easier.

Comment: May I also suggest adding 1 next to the answer to show the answer is correct.